# Phonegap open external browser not woking in first time

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, cordova

I used phonegap to build an app for ios. When i click onto a facebook link, i want to call the facebook app installed in iphone.
The first time, it doesn't happen, i must double click on the home button of iphone for going to the main screen and the app appears. But from the second time (i continue to use this app, not exit it), the fb app appears immediately when the link clicked.

Open facebook app:

```
window.open('fb://profile/123456', '_system', 'location=no');
```

Same problem with browser:

```
window.open(encodeURI('http://facebook.com/abc'), '_system');
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit:**

I saw in logs and found

```
"THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '521.020020' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

How can i make inappbrowser plugin run in background? Thanks!

I'm beginner in xcode, so i don't know where to put:

```
- (void)myPluginMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    // Check command.arguments here.
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* payload = nil;
        // Some blocking logic...
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:payload];
        // The sendPluginResult method is thread-safe.
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to execute the code under onDeviceReady.

Thanks,
Madan

Comment: Yes, i executed my code under onDeviceReady. In fact, i edited my post with the WARNING that i found in logs. Thanks!